# How to get the Xpath of this this menu item?

Tags: xpath

I need to select a menu item that contains certain text, in this case is the text '19061Schwerin'

but inside the li, there is text and also an anchor tag.

I tried this: `$x("//li[contains(., 19061Schwerin)]")`

But it doesnt work, any ideas?

[image]

Comment: It makes life a little easier when a code sample is shared rather than an image from dev tools. Just a friendly reminder

Answer (score 0):

To locate the `li` elements that contain the text "19061 Schwerin" the following xpath will work:

```
//li[contains(normalize-space(.), '19061 Schwerin')]
```

Note: this will find to elements that match this xpath. If you want just the first xpath you can stick a `[1]` at the end of the above xpath.